# Twitter の Bearer Token から、Consumer Key (API Key) と、Consumer Secret (API Secret) を取得 できますか？

Tags: twitter

Twitter の Bearer Token から、Consumer Key (API Key) と、Consumer Secret (API Secret) を取得 できますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

できません。
Bearerトークンは、切符のようなものと考えて下さい。以下に解説があります。

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bearer%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%B3